# android: Stored Images in SqLite is taking 2x more space

Tags: android, sqlite, jpeg

I want to store jpg images in a SqLite database and I am using this code to convert bitmap to array of bytes.

```
            public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);       
                return outputStream.toByteArray();
            }
```

the issue that image take more than 2x of it's size in database

Comment: What does the schema look like?  How are you writing the bytes to the database?

Comment: Why don't you just store the **paths**?

Comment: i'm using blob to storing image into database

Comment: I agree with Der Golem. I see no point in the extra overhead involved in converting to and from a byte array and then writing that data to the database. For me a simpler option is to simply store the image in your app filesystem and then store the path to that file as a text field in your database.

Comment: when I put images in database it's more flexible to move and use in another apps

Comment: read this http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html

Comment: JPEG with 100% quality as you have takes more space than JPEG with the usual quality of around 85%. But then again, storing large data in Android sqlite is a bad idea. Small 2MB cursor window to start with.

Comment: Why are converting the JPEG into a Bitmap object first? You should use the original data.